# Php 1 variable me funciona, pero las otras 3 no

Tags: php, undefined

tengo 3 variables para guardar un mensaje de error, la primera me funciona, pero agregué 3 más y éstas sacan el mensaje de error: Undefined variable:

```
    <?php
if( isset($_GET['Horas']) &&
    isset($_GET['Minutos']) &&
    isset($_GET['Segundos']) &&
    isset($_GET['Nombre']))
    {
        if( empty($_GET['Nombre']) ||
            empty($_GET['Horas']) ||
            empty($_GET['Minutos']) ||
            empty($_GET['Segundos']) ||
            empty($_GET['Duracion'])) 
            {
                echo 'No pueden haber campos vacíos'; 
                ?><a href='index.php'>Volver</a><?php
            }
            else
            {
                $errorHoras;
                $errorMinutos;              
                $errorSegundos;
                $errorDuracion; 

                if(!ctype_digit($_GET['Horas'])){
                    $errorHoras = 'Horas debe tener un valor entero';
                }
                if(!ctype_digit($_GET['Minutos'])){
                    $errorMinutos = 'Minutos debe tener un valor entero';
                }
                if(!ctype_digit($_GET['Segundos'])){
                    $errorSegundos = 'Minutos debe tener un valor entero';
                }
                if(!ctype_digit($_GET['Duracion'])){
                    $errorDuracion = 'Minutos debe tener un valor entero';
                } 

                if(empty($errorHoras) && empty($errorMinutos) && empty($errorSegundos) && empty($errorDuracion)){
                    //Inicializar
                    $valorHora=0;
                    $porcentajeRecargoDiurno=0;
                    $porcentajeRecargoNocturno=0;

                    $horaDeEntrada=$_GET['Horas'];
                    $duracion=$_GET['Duracion'];
                    $horaDeSalida=$horaDeEntrada + $duracion;

                    //La ocupación puede tener 3 opciones, dos sencillas y una doble
                    if(isset($_GET['Desarrollador']))
                    {
                        $valorHora=15000;
                        $porcentajeRecargoDiurno=0.07;
                        $porcentajeRecargoNocturno=0.02;
                    }

                    if(isset($_GET['Diseñador']))
                    {
                        $valorHora=18000;
                        $porcentajeRecargoDiurno=0.05;
                        $porcentajeRecargoNocturno=0.02;
                    }

                    if(isset($_GET['Diseñador'])&& isset($_GET['Desarrollador']))
                    {
                        $valorHora=20000;
                        $porcentajeRecargoDiurno=0.1;
                        $porcentajeRecargoNocturno=0.1;
                    }

                    //calcular horas diurnas y nocturnas
                    //cantidad de evaluaciones
                    $e=$duracion+1;
                    //variable para hacer un ciclo
                    $j=$horaDeEntrada;
                    $i=1;
                    $horasNocturnas=0;

                    while ($i < $e) {
                        if($j>=22){
                            $horasNocturnas = $horasNocturnas + 1;
                        }
                        $j = $j + 1;
                        $i = $i + 1;
                    }

                    $horasDiurnas = $duracion - $horasNocturnas;


                    $salarioBasico = $valorHora * $duracion;                
                    $recargoDiurno = (($valorHora * $porcentajeRecargoDiurno)* $horasDiurnas);
                    $recargoNocturno = (($valorHora * $porcentajeRecargoNocturno)* $horasNocturnas);
                    $salarioNeto = $salarioBasico + $recargoDiurno + $recargoNocturno;

                    echo 'Hora de salida '.$horaDeSalida.'<br>'.
                    'Valor Hora '.$valorHora.'<br>'.
                    'Salario básico '.$salarioBasico.'<br>'.
                    'Porcentaje Recargo Diurno '.$porcentajeRecargoDiurno.'<br>'.
                    'Horas diurnas '.$horasDiurnas.'<br>'.
                    'Recargo diurno '.$recargoDiurno.'<br>'.
                    'Porcentaje Recargo Nocturno '.$porcentajeRecargoNocturno.'<br>'.
                    'Horas nocturnas '.$horasNocturnas.'<br>'.
                    'Recargo nocturno '.$recargoNocturno.'<br><br>'.

                    'Salario neto '.$salarioNeto.'<br>'.
                    'Nombre '.$_GET['Nombre'].'<br>'.
                    '<img src="'.$_GET['Nombre'].'.jpg" width="50" height="50" />';
                }
                else {
                    echo $errorHoras.'<br>'.
                    $errorMinutos.'<br>'. //Error aquí
                    $errorSegundos.'<br>'. //Error aquí
                    $errorDuracion.'<br>';  //Error aquí
                } 
            } //else del if empty
     }
     else
     {
        echo 'Error, variables no definidas ';
        ?><a href='index.php'>Volver</a><?php


     }



?>
```

Comment: prueba inicializandolas con un valor vacio ejemplo: `$mivar = "";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El tema viene cuando no hay error/valor por asignar a dichas variables; por tal motivo te devuelven eso.

La solución puede ser con uso de objetos o arreglos, mas dado el ejemplo brindado, por rapidez y simplicidad te recomiendo arreglos.

```
$errores = [];

if(!ctype_digit($_GET['Horas'])){
    $errores['horas'] = 'Horas debe tener un valor entero';
}
if(!ctype_digit($_GET['Minutos'])){
    $errores['minutos'] = 'Minutos debe tener un valor entero';
}
if(!ctype_digit($_GET['Segundos'])){
    $errores['segundos'] = 'Minutos debe tener un valor entero';
}
if(!ctype_digit($_GET['Duracion'])){
    $errores['duracion'] = 'Minutos debe tener un valor entero';
}
```

De tal modo que al final en lugar de devolver una cadena concatenada, podrías solo devolver los valores en el arreglo en caso de que existan.

Dada la solución del problema planteado, no parece los más óptimo; pero para ello te recomiendo las lecturas de:

- [Solid, cinco principios básicos de diseño de clases](https://www.genbetadev.com/paradigmas-de-programacion/solid-cinco-principios-basicos-de-diseno-de-clases).

Comment: Gracias Chofoteddy... aguegué esto para mostrar los errores por si a alguien le sirve: if ($errores): ?>
           <ul style="color: #f00;">
              <?php foreach ($errores as $error): ?>
                 <li> <?php echo $error ?> </li>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
           </ul>
        <?php endif;